# Unable to create the 'TodoItem' Easy table in Azure Portal

Tags: node.js, azure, xamarin.forms

I've been following this tutorial on how to create a backend service for my xamarin application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started

I have managed to create the Web App Service and have connected it to my Azure SQL database and have successfully initialized the Easy Tables function for my service.

However, when I try to create the TodoItem table, I receive the following error message:

Table creation error :

> There was an error while creating table 'TodoItem'.
>   '{"Code":"InternalServerError","Message":"{\r\n  \"Message\": \"An
>   error has occurred.\",\r\n  \"ExceptionMessage\": \"CREATE TABLE
>   permission denied in database 'master'.\",\r\n  \"ExceptionType\":

I'm not sure as to why I'm receiving this error, and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Make sure that the connection string you provided in step 2b is pointed to your SQL Database and not to the "Master" database. Specifically, check the Initial Catalog value you've provided in the connection string. This error makes me think it's pointed to the master DB and not your actual TODO Database.

Also, be aware that Easy tables are being deprecated in November: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/removing-easy-tables-and-easy-apis-from-azure-app-service/

Comment: @MikeWo thanks for the reply. I'm new to Azure, how exactly can I differentiate between the Master database and the SQL Database I'm trying to create, within my connection string?

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Maybe include that in your question (make sure to remove any actual password). Look at the answer that Adam provided as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your app seems to be connected to master.

```
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'
```

Add database name to connection string.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Azure SQL DB create permission for this app service.

Comment: I'm struggling to find out how to do this, can it be done within the Azure portal?